# How to use CLNTCONN channels in AMQCLCHL.TAB file from a Vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, ibm-mq

In my Vb.net application I'm using IBM MQ v7.5 Managed client connection to connect to a queue manager. Until now I have provided channel name and host name in a .Config file and call the following:

```
MQQueueManager(Qmanagername, Channel, Host)
```

But Now I have a AMQCLCHL.TAB file with the channel details. How can I have my Vb.net application use the channel name and host name from the AMQCLCHL.TAB file.

Comment: Thanks downvote, if you don't have any answer just downvote.

Comment: Do you want your application to directly use the connection details that are embedded in the AMQCLCHL.TAB (channel table) file, or do you simply want to extract the values from the file so that you can put them in your applications .config file?

Comment: I want to directly use the values. for that i also set some paths.

Comment: Is your application using .NET manged or unmanaged MQ mode?

Comment: managed MQ mode. We have MQ manager name, channel name and host name. And without using AMQCLCHL.TAB file, we just calling the New MQQueueManager(Qmanagername, Channel, Host) and we are able to connect. But now we dont want to specify the channel and host and want to be took from AMQCLCHL.TAB file.

Comment: MQ version is 7.5

Answer (score 1):

You need to let the application know the location of the channel table file.  The [IBM Knowledge center](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029600_.htm) shows this can be done in three ways with managed client connection type:

- Using the .NET application configuration file. In the CHANNELS section, use the keys ChannelDefinitionDirectory to specify the directory where the table is located, and ChannelDefinitionFile to specify the file name.
- Using the environment variables MQCHLLIB to specify the directory where the table is located, and MQCHLTAB to specify the file name of the table.
- Using the client configuration file. In the CHANNELS stanza, use the attributes ChannelDefinitionDirectory to specify the directory where the table is located, and ChannelDefinitionFile to specify the file name.

You can then change your call to drop the channel and hostname and it will pickup the channel table that you specified using one of the three ways described above.

```
New MQQueueManager(Qmanagername)
```

**Update to include additional information from the comments**

If your application runs on the same server as the queue manager it will by default connect in unmanaged mode using server bindings if you do not force it to use client mode. This is described in detail in the [Knowledge Center](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029480_.htm).

You can force it to a client mode by setting the environment variable NMQ_MQ_LIB.

For unmanaged MQ client mode use `NMQ_MQ_LIB=mqic.dll`

For managed client mode use `NMQ_MQ_LIB=managed`

The `MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY` hashtable property can also used to force it to use client mode.

Unmanaged MQ client mode example:

```
Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, "MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT");
return new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, properties);
```

Managed MQ client mode example:

```
Hashtable properties = new Hashtable();
properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED");
return new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, properties);
```

Comment: I'm doing it using second way. but what do you mean by,
"You can then change your call to drop the channel and hostname and it will pickup the channel table that you specified using one of the three ways described above."

Comment: I have done this and again it is working. But if i remove the environment variable (testing purpose) again it is working. It should show some error but nothing.

Comment: No, I'm saying it is working with or without environment variable that should not be when the environment variable is not set.

Comment: Ok, let me check.

Comment: I can't rename the file as I don't have admin access on my machine. Is there any other way to test?

Comment: working fine it i remove the environment variable or change MQCHLTAB = abc.txt ( That doen't exist).

Comment: Tried that but same. nothing has changed.

Comment: yeah we have machines on which only MQ client is installed. For them it is not working.

Comment: Now I'm able to modify the name of MQCHLTAB file. So I copied that file on desktop and give the path of desktop. But now it is not working.

Comment: I'm getting MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR when calling "New MQQueueManager(Qmanagername)"

Comment: Just FYI guys, SO is *not* a forum. Anything from Pirate that is relevant to the question should be captured as an update to the question. Anything relevant to Josh's answer should be an update to the answer. Most of what is in the comments will never help anyone because it isn't indexed. If the comments are voted up they get shown out of order. After the original question is answered and you move past the point of failure, **ask another question** if you need to continue debugging.  There's 2 or 3 good questions tied up in comments nobody will ever see.